# How can I get the d3.js bar chart start from 0 instead of from the top

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’m trying to build a dashboard that displays a skier’s performance on a bar graph. On the x-axis, I have different runs (total of 14 runs). On the Y-axis, I have calculated a score that ranges from -1.5 to 1 second. Preferably, I don’t want the bars to start from the upper top; I want them to start from 0. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

[image]

Here's my index.html with all the d3.js code:
the csv file can be found on [csv](http://www.cmagelssen.no/bib5.csv)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DASHBORD</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #d9ecf2;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <script>
    
    // 1. Her velger jeg body elementet og appender et svg element hvor vår figur skal plasseres
    const height = 600
    const width = 960
    const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 30}
    const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
    const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("fill", "#1aa6b7")

    const render = data => {

        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.RATIO))
            .range([0, innerHeight]);

        const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d => d.RUN ))
            .range([0, innerWidth])
            .padding(0.1)

        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
        const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)

        const g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

        yAxis(g.append("g"))
        xAxis(g.append("g"))

        g.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", d => yScale(d.RATIO))
            .attr("x", d => xScale(d.RUN))
    }

    d3.csv("bib5.csv").then(data => {
        data.forEach(d => 
        d.RATIO = +d.RATIO
        )
        render(data)
    }
   
    )
 

    </script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is by adding `.attr("y", d => innerHeight - yScale(d.RATIO))` to your `rect`s. You can adapt this to make sure that the height is always positive, and then position the bars accordingly.

```js
// 1. Her velger jeg body elementet og appender et svg element hvor vår figur skal plasseres
const height = 300
const width = 700
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 30
}
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

const render = data => {
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-5, 5])
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);

  const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.RUN))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .padding(0.1)

  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)

  const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

  g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('v', d => d.RATIO)
    .attr("x", d => xScale(d.RUN))
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? yScale(d.RATIO) - yScale(0) : yScale(0) - yScale(d.RATIO))
    .attr("y", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? yScale(0) : yScale(d.RATIO))
    .attr("fill", d => d.RATIO < 0 ? 'red' : 'green')

  yAxis(g.append("g"))
  xAxis(g.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(0,${yScale(0)})`))
}

const data = d3.range(14).map(i => ({
  RATIO: -1 + Math.random() * 2,
  RUN: i
}));
render(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222825/discussion-between-ruben-helsloot-and-christian-magelssen).